# display data in table view using Java jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I'm new to java jsp. I try to display the data into table view. But it's seem like having some problem where if i change my rowspan and the display of td for another person.

```
<tr><td rowspan="3"><%=owner.getOname()%></td> </tr>
```

Does anyone able to give some guide? Here is my code.

```
<%@page import="com.entity.Owner"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.math.BigDecimal"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="com.entity.Pen"%>
<%@page import="com.session.PenFacadeLocal"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%
    try{
        //initialisation
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        PenFacadeLocal penFacade = (PenFacadeLocal)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/pen");

        List<Owner> ownerList = penFacade.listByOwner(); %>

        <table border="1" align="center" style="width:50%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <th>Brand of Pen</th>
                <th>Colour</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <% for (Owner owner : ownerList) { %>
        <tr><td rowspan="3"><%=owner.getOname()%></td> </tr>

            <% for (Pen pen : owner.getPenSet()) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=pen.getPbrand()%></td>
                <td><%=pen.getPcolour()%></td>
            </tr>
            <% }
            out.print("</br>");
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.print("OK : " + e.getMessage());
    }
%>

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

the table view that i would like to get is 
[table view that i should get](https://www.dropbox.com/s/53b7rbe49o9e7z2/Capture.JPG?dl=0)

this is the table output that i get
[table view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fv8a3p5blx12obm/Capture1.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: You need to be more specific: "it's seem like having some problem" is not a proper description of an issue. What's failing? Are you getting any errors? How is your table displayed? How should it be displayed?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hi, sorry it's my bad that did not mention if vry clear. i have edit my question. i did not get any error but only the table displayed is different with what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code,

```
<% for (Owner owner : ownerList) { 
    // assuming getPenSet() returns set object.
    Set<Pen> pens = owner.getPenSet();
%>
    <!-- Here I am adding rowspan value dynamically, depends no of pens.
     Adding `+1` to no of pens because the Owner is also counted for the rowspan. -->
    <tr><td rowspan="<%=pens.size()+1>"><%=owner.getOname()%></td> </tr>

        <% for (Pen pen : pens) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=pen.getPbrand()%></td>
            <td><%=pen.getPcolour()%></td>
        </tr>
        <% }
       // no need of <br> inside of `<table>`
       // out.print("</br>");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide. i have try it and it give me the table that i want with some modified of your code. :D